# Trying to get an image from a C++ dll in C# using DLLImport

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to get an image from a C++ DLL with DLLImport by getting a byte array but I get an AccessViolationException.

DLL Import function:

```cs
 [DllImport("DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern IntPtr getDPimgPtr();
```

C++:

```cpp
unsigned char* getDPimgPtr();
```

Usage:

```
 public int imgPtr
        {
            get
            {
                IntPtr result = getDPimgPtr(); 
                byte[] managedArray = new byte[imgSnippetSize];
                try
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(result, managedArray, 0, imgSnippetSize);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
                }
                return BitConverter.ToInt32(managedArray, 0);
            }
        }
```

And this is how I get the byte array in the end to convert to an image:

```cs
  byte[] arr = new byte[dc.imgSnippetSize];

  Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)imgPtr, arr, 0, imgSnippetSize);
```

I get the exception at the `Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)imgPtr, arr, 0, imgSnippetSize);` line.

Comment: We need the C++ header and possible the relevant implementation part to help.

Comment: The header part is there: unsigned char* getDPimgPtr()

Comment: Question edited, please check. @SimonMourier

Comment: Where is the implementation? Reason is there are chances your release the pointer before .NET get s a chance to read it

Comment: I suppose I added it in the question, look at the very bottom. That's exactly it. Nothing else really.

Comment: Where in memory is result?  Is it in allocated memory?  A method stores data on the execution stack which is disposed when you return from the method.  So result cannot be a local variable in the getDPimgPtr().

Comment: Okay, I tried storing it in a global variable but nothing changed. Same error.

Comment: It's hard to see what you are trying to do. Here with `BitConverter.ToInt32` you are using your C++ pointer to get another pointer at the start of the array returned by the C++. Is it what you intended ? If it is, are you sure that you your platform is 32-bit ? If the pointer is 64-bit you only get half of it. Also, your `managedArray` is deleted as soon as `imgPtr` returns. It could be intended, but then why copy more than 4 bytes if you only use 4 ?

Comment: All I want to do is convert that IntPtr to a byte array and to an image, I don't care how, so if you can recommend me a way that'd be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: If the pointer returned by your C++ call is directly the image, You just need the first copy, and return the managed `byte[]` directly, without any cast or `BitConverter`.